# CartoDB or Leaflet.js get coordinates of point clicked?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, carto, popup

Using CartoDB or Leaflet.js is it possible to retrieve the coordinates of the point on the map clicked when opening an infowindow?

Comment: In leaflet you can get the coordinates of point on mouse click. check this for more http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#events

Answer (score 1):

Thats worked

http://www.leafletjs.com/reference.html#events was helpful

the code would be:

```
map.on('click', function(e)  
  {

  tempLatitude = e.latlng.lat;

  tempLongitude = e.latlng.lng;

});
```